# The log.trc file is missing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

The `log.trc file` is missing on the server, but there are archived trace files like (log_15.trc, log_16.trc, log_17.trc, log_18.trc, and log_19.trc).  Is this something to be concerned about?

Is there a way to create the `log.trc` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing to be concerned about. The [default trace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/default-trace-enabled-server-configuration-option) creates up to 5 rollover files, each with a max size to 20MB, and a incremental number is automatically appended to the file name. The older files are automatically deleted once the max of 5 files is reached.

You can query the trace in T-SQL using [`fn_trace_gettable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-trace-gettable-transact-sql), specifying only the base file name `log.trc` along with the number of files to read or `default` to read all available trace files.

Comment: Dan, When I try to run the query using fn_trace_gettable, I receive the following error message:  Msg 19050, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Trace file name 'log.trc' is invalid.
I also get this message if I use one of the specific trace files.

Comment: @jbeck, are you specifying the full path to the trace file? The exact location will vary depending on your SQL version and installation folder.